# I have installed a Magento theme but could not see Homepage block for this theme

Tags: home-page

New them installed Homepge block is not shown, only Home page for luma is available. How shall I change the homepage now?
I tried creating new homepage and linked it Store >> General >> Web >> Default page >> CMS Home Page.
But it did not work.

Comment: Which type of block you have add on home page ? Can you please add some text on cms home page and check display on frontend or not.

Comment: I added "Test Text" in cms home page but still its not reflecting.

Comment: Disable all type of cache and then check.

Comment: I tried disabling all types cache and my webpage title shows the expected title but content of that homepage is same as that of the old homepage. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the bellow steps to for your theme:-

> Step 1) Install your theme module First.
>
> Step 2) In Content->Design-> configuration, Assign your theme according to your store.
>
> Step 3)  Store -> General -> Web -> Default page -> Your Theme CMS Home Page

Clear cache and check.

Still, you don't get you blocks on the home page then check theme blocks are imported/Enable in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Login into admin

From left menu Content -> Block
Then edit block having identifier "home-page-block" Check following screenshot.

[image]

Disable this block. Home page content comes from this static block. Check following screenshot

[image]

Please write here still if you have any issue.